# Using .outerWidth() & .outerHeight() with the 'resize' event to center a child element in parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, outerheight, outerwidth

I am attempting to write some JavaScript code that will allow me to center a child element within it's parent using padding. Then using the same function to recalculate the spacing using the 'resize' event. Before you start asking me why i am not doing this with CSS, this code is only a small part of a larger project. I have simplified the code as the rest of the code works and would only serve to confuse the subject.

**Calculating the space** - This is the function that caculates the amount of space to be used on either side of the child element.

```
($outer.outerWidth() - $inner.outerWidth()) / 2;
($outer.outerHeight() - $inner.outerHeight()) / 2;
```

**The problem**

Although i have successfully managed to get the desired results with margin. Padding is causing me problems.

1. It appears to be increasing the width on the outer element when resized
2. It does not center the child element perfectly (there appears to be an offset)
3. The inner element collapses on resize and becomes invisible.

I realize that there may be some fundamentals regarding padding that are causing my problems however after numerous console logs and observing the data returned i still can't put my finger on the problem. Any suggestion would be very welcome. It may turn out that this is not feasible at all.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="demo" class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.outer {
  width:97%;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:20px;
}

.inner {
  width:40%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:grey;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var $outer = $(".outer");
var $inner = $(".inner");

var getSpace = function(axis)  {

  if (axis.toLowerCase() == "x") {

    return ($outer.outerWidth() - $inner.outerWidth()) / 2;

  } else if (axis.toLowerCase() == "y") {

    return ($outer.outerHeight() - $inner.outerHeight()) / 2;

  }  

}

var renderStyle = function(spacingType) {

  var lateralSpace = getSpace("x");  
  var verticalSpace = getSpace("y");

  var $element;

  if (spacingType == "padding") {
      $element = $outer;
  } else if (spacingType == "margin") {
      $element = $inner;
    }

  $.each(["top", "right", "bottom", "left"], function(index, direction) {
    if (direction == "top" || direction == "bottom") {
      $element.css(spacingType + "-" + direction, verticalSpace);
    }
    else if (direction == "right" || direction == "left") {
      $element.css(spacingType + "-" + direction, lateralSpace);
    }                                     
  });                
}; 

var renderInit = function() {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    renderStyle("padding");

  });

  $(window).on("resize", function() {

    renderStyle("padding");

  });

}

renderInit();
```

**EXAMPLE** - [link](http://codepen.io/fmrogers/pen/VPpQdY?editors=0110)

Comment: Combine .innerHeight and .innerWidth() with it and it should be fine.

Comment: Sorry not sure i understand exactly what you mean, where should i include this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I completely disagree with this approach to horizontally centring an element, hopefully this will help you on your way.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0uxx2ujg/

JavaScript:

```
var outer = $('.outer'), inner = $('.inner');
function centreThatDiv(){ 
    var requiredPadding = outer.outerWidth() / 2 - (inner.outerWidth() / 2);
    console.log(requiredPadding);
    outer.css('padding', '0 ' + requiredPadding + 'px').css('width','auto');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // fire on page load
    centreThatDiv();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    // fire on window resize
    centreThatDiv();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Centre me!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer{ width:80%; height:300px; margin:10%; background: tomato; }
.inner{ width:60px; height:60px; background:white; }
```

Furthered on from why I disagree with this approach - JavaScript shouldn't be used to lay things out. Sure - it can be, if it *really* needs to be used; but for something as simple as centring an element, it's not necessary at all. Browsers handle resizing CSS elements themselves, so by using JS you introduce more headaches for yourself further down the line.

Here's a couple of examples of how you can achieve this in CSS only:

text-align:center & display:inline-block https://jsfiddle.net/0uxx2ujg/1/

position:absolute & left:50% https://jsfiddle.net/0uxx2ujg/2/ (this can be used for vertically centring too which is trickier than horizontal)

Comment: Thank you, i have tested you code and it brings me one step further but as you said (and as i am realizing myself) this is proving to be a greater headache then is required for the end result. My original intent was to make a script that would responsively re position elements that are absolutely  positioned. Some where down line i decided to include margin and padding and that where things started going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the new CSS class to adjust for elements size on  $window.onresize = function () {
           //add your code 
        };

Comment: are you referring to the inner element collapsing on when resized ?

Comment: Don't give the padding then its become auto responsive

Comment: Ah i see. Thank you.

Comment: if got resolution then plz give ratings to my Answer :)